# JQuery 1.11.2 cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I recently 'upgraded' from JQuery 1.3 (I know, I know, this project is 6 years old and I'm taking it over from another developer in hopes to get it done...properly) to 1.11.2, using JQuery Migrate v1.2.1 since going version to version might take me the rest of my life.

Anyways, I'm coming across minimal issues, most of which I am able to repair, however this one stumps me. The following code works perfectly fine in 1.5.1, but throws this error in 1.11.2 **"Cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'".**

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setupEvents();
});

function setupEvents() {
    $('.dmr-id').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadConsumerServiceDialog();
    });

    function loadConsumerServiceDialog() {
        $('#consumer-service-dialog').dialog("destroy");
        $('#consumer-service-dialog').dialog("open");

        $('#consumer-service-dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 740,
            width: 1000,
            title: 'Consumer Service Detailed Relations',
            resizable: false
        });
    }
```

If I add comment out the 'destroy' method, it throws the same error on the 'open' method. It seems like an obvious error, the dialog is not initialized, but how could it be initialized prior to opening? I don't see why it is being thrown in 1.11.2 and not the other versions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not opposed to figuring it out myself if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message clearly describes what is wrong. You are trying to open or destroy a dialog before it exists. You need to first ensure that it is a dialog before you attempt to destroy or open it. I'd suggest testing to see if it has the ui-dialog class.

Comment: I understand what it is saying, what I don't understand is why would this work in previous versions and not this one? It seems like it's a pretty standard issue, if a dialog doesn't exist, it doesn't exist no matter the version, no?

Comment: Because the library was pretty much re-written? Why this requirement was added is a question that would need to be directed at the jQuery UI dev team

Comment: I think this would be better if it just silently ignored the call rather than throwing an error, though i'm sure they have some good reason for making it throw an error instead.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my curiosity got the best of me :) Thank you for your help. I also found a post stating that the newest JQuery doesn't allow methods to be called on items that are not initialized. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't destroy or open a dialog before it exists. I suggest creating the dialog up front, and then just opening or closing it later.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setupEvents();
});

function setupEvents() {
    var consumerServiceDialog = $('#consumer-service-dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 740,
        width: 1000,
        title: 'Consumer Service Detailed Relations',
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('.dmr-id').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadConsumerServiceDialog();
    });

    function loadConsumerServiceDialog() {
        //consumerServiceDialog.dialog("destroy"); // why destroy it?
        consumerServiceDialog.dialog("open");
    }
```